# Filtering reporting services dataset based on proc

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a reporting services dataset returned from a stored proc. I'd like to further filter the data based on a parameter. I've added that filter to the dataset but it's still giving me all of the data. Does filtering work with a proc based dataset or just with a cmd text based select statement?

Before I get bombarded with 'just add the fourth parameter to the proc' type answers, this isn't an option in this case otherwise believe me, I'd prefer that solution.

Comment: How are you adding the filter to the dataset?  If you are filtering it before passing it to the report control, it should be fine.

Comment: I added the filter to the dataset using the report designer in Business Inteligence Developement Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I have it figured out I think but I'm not sure why it's doing what it's doing. When I look at the data from the stored proc using `sql management studio`, the data field I'm trying to filter looks fine, no added spaces etc. For instance I can do `WHERE field1 = 'Loaded'` and it filters fine there. When I add the filter into `reporting services` on the dataset, I had to do a trim on the field for it to match. It seems as though `reporting services` is added spaces to the data for some reason.

For instance I had to do,

```
trim(Fields!ReportDepartment.Value)=trim(Parameters!department.Value)
```

for it to match.

Anyone else had this issue?